# Crop simple bounding box with openCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, crop, contour

I have some images with a black background and some text in the corner:

[image: This is what it looks like]

I'm trying to do a rectangular crop to make it look like:

[image: Goal]

The text on the sides as well as the window dimensions are of varying sizes. My code isn't cropping correctly, what am I doing wrong?

I've tried removing the text in the bottom right corner first and cropping, that doesn't work either.

```
def crop_cont(img):
     gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
     _,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,15,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

     _, contours, _= cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
     cnt = contours[0]

     x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)

     crop = img[y:y+h,x:x+w]

return crop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is in general ok. The issue is that you are using contours[0]. You have to find the right contour (there are more than one). In this particular example, the right contour is the biggest one. Just iterate all found contours and find the one with the biggest area.

Comment: The largest contour sometimes includes the text though (if the text surrounds the image window). How would I find the largest contour ignoring the text?

Comment: Then you have to find the right criteria. For example, look not for the largest contour but that for one with the right angles. Or you might want to remove the text in the preparation phase (before findContours).